# Not able to display List of objects in JSP page based on the given input using Spring MVC JPA using Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, jsp, jpa

I am trying to display List of Student objects based on their Course on JSP page using Spring MVC and JPA using Spring Boot

I am using the JSP page `searchByCourse.jsp` page as shown below and on the JSP page, the list of student objects based on the given course is not displayed.
And also the methods in the repository file `StudentRepo.java` are not showing any output as well. I have marked them in the comments in the `StudentController.java`.

I am not able to understand where I made the mistake.
Your help would be really appreciated.

Below are the files I am using.

**Student.java**

```
package com.springcourse.springmvcboot.model;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Student 
{
    @Id
    private int studID;
    private String studName;
    private String studCourse;

    public String getStudCourse() {
        return studCourse;
    }

    public void setStudCourse(String studCourse) {
        this.studCourse = studCourse;
    }

    public int getStudID() {
        return studID;
    }
    
    public void setStudID(int studID) {
        this.studID = studID;
    }
    
    public String getStudName() {
        return studName;
    }
    
    public void setStudName(String studName) {
        this.studName = studName;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Student [studID=" + studID + ", studName=" + studName + ", studCourse=" + studCourse + "]";
    }
        
}
```

**StudentController.java**

```
package com.springcourse.springmvcboot;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import com.springcourse.springmvcboot.dao.StudentRepo;
import com.springcourse.springmvcboot.model.Student;

@Controller
public class StudentController 
{
    @Autowired
    StudentRepo studrepo;
    
    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String home()
    {
        return "home.jsp";
    } 
    
    @RequestMapping("/addStudent")
    public String addStudent(Student stud)
    {
        studrepo.save(stud);
        return "home.jsp";
    }
    
    @RequestMapping("/getStudent")
    public ModelAndView getStudent(@RequestParam int studID)
    {
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("showStudent.jsp");
        Student student = studrepo.findById(studID).orElse(new Student());
        mv.addObject(student);
        
        return mv;
    }
    
    @RequestMapping("/deleteStudent")
    public ModelAndView deleteStudent(@RequestParam int studID)
    {
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("deleteStudent.jsp");
        Student student = studrepo.findById(studID).orElse(new Student());
        studrepo.deleteById(studID);
        mv.addObject(student);
        
        return mv;
    }
    
    @RequestMapping("/deleteAllStudent")
    public ModelAndView deleteAllStudent()
    {
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("deleteAllStudent.jsp");
        studrepo.deleteAll();
        
        return mv;
    }
    
    @RequestMapping("/searchByCourse")
    public ModelAndView searchByCourse(@RequestParam String studCourse)
    {
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("searchByCourse.jsp");
        List<Student> studList = studrepo.findByStudCourse(studCourse);
        
        mv.addObject("stlist", studList);
        
        System.out.println(studrepo.findByStudCourse("Java"));//Not displaying any output
        System.out.println(studrepo.findByStudIDLessThan(105));
        System.out.println(studrepo.findByStudCourseSorted("Java"));//Not displaying any output
        
        return mv;
    }
}
```

**StudentRepo.java**

```
package com.springcourse.springmvcboot.dao;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

import com.springcourse.springmvcboot.model.Student;

public interface StudentRepo extends CrudRepository<Student, Integer>
{
    List<Student> findByStudCourse(String studCourse);
    
    List<Student> findByStudIDLessThan(int studID);
    
    
    @Query("from Student where studCourse=?1 order by studName")
    List<Student> findByStudCourseSorted(String studCourse);
}
```

The JSP file used to display

**searchByCourse.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>

The List of Students are <br>

<c:forEach items="${stlist}" var="st">
        <li>${st}</li>
</c:forEach>

</body>
</html>
```

**And finally the pom.xml file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.5.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.springcourse</groupId>
    <artifactId>springmvcjpaboot</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>springmvcjpaboot</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring MVC with Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.tomcat/tomcat-jasper -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-jasper</artifactId>
    <version>9.0.39</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jstl/jstl -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>jstl</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/jstl -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>

        
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```